# How much Hours overlap between 2 date ranges

Tags: c#, datetime, overlap

I have a few date ranges, I want to know how many hour overlap between them:

**Example:**

```
Range 1: from 1/1/2013 10:00AM to 1/1/2013 1:00PM
Range 2: from 1/1/2013 12:00PM to 1/1/2013 5:00PM
```

The result should be: **1 hour**

Comment: Have you tried to play with the methods exposed by the `DateTime` class?

Comment: @ItalyM see my cooments on the "right" answer (which was't at the time i wrote comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
  DateTime dtBegin, dtBegin1,  dtBegin2, dtEnd, dtEnd1, dtEnd2;
  dtBegin = dtBegin1 < dtBegin2 ? dtBegin1 : dtBegin2;
  dtEnd = dtEnd1 > dtEnd2 ? dtEnd1 : dtEnd2;
  TimeSpan range = dtEnd - dtBegin;
  int hours = range.Hours
```

Comment: -1 for not reading the question. Look again, this is not what he is asking. Also, you are right that the [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee293619(v=bts.10).aspx) class does exist, but it obviously has nothing to do with this question and isn't intended as a reference to that class.

Comment: What is he asking about? I read it several times...

Comment: need a very little changes with start and ends date but it give the important part of the answer

Comment: If you look carefully, he asked for **overlapping time** of two date & time ranges, not just the time between two datetimes.

Comment: @tnw Ah, that's the deal... I thought overlap == pass.

Comment: Edited it so it gets the overlapping hours.

Comment: public class DatePeriod
{
    public long ticks1;
    public long ticks2;

    public DatePeriod(long date1, long date2)
    {
        ticks1 = Math.Min(date1, date2);
        ticks2 = Math.Max(date1, date2);
    }

    public TimeSpan Overlap(DatePeriod dp)
    {
        if (ticks2 >= dp.ticks1 && ticks2 <= dp.ticks2 || ticks1 >= dp.ticks1 && ticks2 <= dp.ticks2)
            return new TimeSpan(Math.Min(Math.Abs(dp.ticks1 - ticks2), Math.Abs(ticks1 - dp.ticks2)));
        return new TimeSpan();
    }
}

Comment: Usage: TimeSpan ts = dp1.Overlap(dp2);Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalHours);

Comment: DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0);
            DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1, 14, 0, 0);
            DateTime dt3 = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1, 13, 0, 0);
            DateTime dt4 = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1, 15, 0, 0);
            DatePeriod dp1 = new DatePeriod(dt1.Ticks, dt2.Ticks);
            DatePeriod dp2 = new DatePeriod(dt3.Ticks, dt4.Ticks);